# Sending data through a serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

am doing some surveillance project...  i need to make some serialport data communication between two systems ... here i could find available com ports in my system through which i need to send and receive some data...is it possible in .net framework 1.1 ? is there is any option?

System.IO.Ports is not available .net 1.1

Comment: -1 for caps and not taking the time to properly format your question into coherent sentences. If you want help, have the decency to phrase your question like a human being.

Comment: Its not fair to down vote if formatting is the reason.

Comment: english could not be his mother language

Comment: But even a spell checker would have detected those spelling mistakes ... Bad grammar is acceptable for non-english speakers but spelling is much less forgivable.

Comment: "Text Speak" and "Tweet Speak" are OK on StackOverflow. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215908/hold-questions-that-use-text-speak. If you have an objection, then its up to you to fix and not the person with writing it. (Personally, I disagree, but who am I...).

Answer (score 2):

When I needed to do some serial port work back in 1.1, I found an article written by Noah Coad that uses the MSComm OCX control and that ended up working for me.  You can find his article at http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=320.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For .net 1.1 I used [OpenNETCF.IO.Serial](http://www.opennetcf.com/downloads/agreement.aspx?s=OpenNETCF.IO.Serial) because serial support was added to .net in version 2.0. It is for the compact framework but I used it for both compact devices and regular windows apps. You get the source code so you can modify it yourself which is what I did.

It basically creates a c# wrapper around the serial function imported out of kernel32.dll.

You might also want to have a look at [How to capture a serial port that disappears because the usb cable gets unplugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286184)

Here is the code that I used to call it

```
     using OpenNETCF.IO.Serial;

     public static Port port;
     private DetailedPortSettings portSettings;
     private Mutex UpdateBusy = new Mutex();

     // create the port
     try
     {
        // create the port settings
        portSettings = new HandshakeNone();
        portSettings.BasicSettings.BaudRate=BaudRates.CBR_9600;

        // create a default port on COM3 with no handshaking
        port = new Port("COM3:", portSettings);

        // define an event handler
        port.DataReceived +=new Port.CommEvent(port_DataReceived);

        port.RThreshold = 1;    
        port.InputLen = 0;      
        port.SThreshold = 1;    
        try
        {
           port.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
           port.Close();
        }
     }
     catch
     {
        port.Close();
     }

     private void port_DataReceived()
     {

        // since RThreshold = 1, we get an event for every character
        byte[] inputData = port.Input;

        // do something with the data
        // note that this is called from a read thread so you should 
        // protect any data pass from here to the main thread using mutex
        // don't forget the use the mutex in the main thread as well
        UpdateBusy.WaitOne();
        // copy data to another data structure
        UpdateBusy.ReleaseMutex();

     }

     private void port_SendBuff()
     {
        byte[] outputData = new byte[esize];
        crc=0xffff;
        j=0;
        outputData[j++]=FS;
        //  .. more code to fill up buff
        outputData[j++]=FS;
        // number of chars sent is determined by size of outputData
        port.Output = outputData;
     }

     // code to close port
     if (port.IsOpen)
     {
        port.Close();
     }
     port.Dispose();
```

Comment: Okay, so where's the juicy part (the port_DataReceived())?

Answer (score 0):

Are you constrained to .NET 1.1? If .NET 2.0 is available to you, you can use the [SerialPort.GetPortNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames.aspx) method to retrieve a list of serial ports on the local host. The [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class is in the [System.IO.Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.aspx) namespace.

Comment: System.IO.Ports is not in .net 1.1